# あなたがこの文のおかしいと思うところは？

Tags: grammar, syntax, relative-clauses

The structure strikes me because the underlying transformation seems to be like this:

```
[　あなたが　]　[　この文の　　～ところを　]　[　おかしいと　]　思う
[　あなたが　]　[　この文の　　＿＿＿＿＿　]　[　おかしいと　]　思う　ところは～
```

Another similar example is:

```
[　僕が　]　[　君の　　～ところが　]　好きだ
[　僕が　]　[　君の　　＿＿＿＿＿　]　好きな　ところは～
```

This structure is unusual because the adjective 君の does not modify anything after transformation. The grammatical word order should have been:

```
[　[　僕が　]　　[　＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿　]　好きな　]　[　君の　]　[　＿　]　ところは～
```

Here is my question:

1. Is it possible to say, 僕が君の　好きな/好きだと思う　のは、そういうところだ (I suppose no).
2. Apart from と思う and 好きだ, are there any other verbs can be used in this way?

Comment: Interesting question, but I think you could improve it by explaining what you find strange about the sentences. How do you attempt to parse them? Do you interpret the の as possessive-の or relative-clause-が-turned-の? Is the reason you want to move あなたが that that would allow you to parse the の as a possessive の?

Comment: あなたがこの文のおかしいと思うところは is natural.
この文のおかしいとあなたが思うところは sounds awkward, but it is acceptable in conversation not a written sentence.
この文の、おかしいとあなたが思うところは may be better.
この文について、おかしいとあなたが思うところは is natural.

Comment: 僕が君のすきなところ is natural. 君の僕が好きなところ is acceptable in conversation, but you need a pause between 君の and 僕が好きなところ. On the contrary, there needs no pause to say 僕が君のすきなところ, it's natural and smooth.

Comment: @dainichi, I thought it was possessive-の but an attributive phrase embedded in another one looks somewhat strange to me. I wonder if this structure is just an exception or can be explained in normal ways.

Comment: @noel_lapin, it seems that when multiple の and が are used, the word order becomes important or it will be difficult to understand.

Comment: @noel_lapin 僕がすきな、君のところ or 僕がすきな君のところ? (is there a difference with/out comma?)

Comment: @YangMuye, you say *the adjective 君の does not modify anything after transformation.*  I think it still does -- it's just that there's a phrase interpolated in between the の phrase and the noun it modifies.

Comment: @Kokoroatari 「僕が好きな君のところ」はちょっと変ですね･･･「好きな+ところ」は、切れないのかも？

Answer (score 0):

1.
natural / acceptable

> 僕が 君を　好きだと思うのは　そういうところだ
>   僕が 君を　好きに思うのは　そういうところだ
>   僕が 君を　好きなのは　そういうところだ
>   僕は 君の　～が　好きだ
>   僕は 君の　～なところが　好きだ
>   僕は 君の　～を　好きだと思う
>   僕が 好きなところは 君の ～だ

not possible

> 僕が 君の　好きな/好きだと思う　のは、そういうところだ (君「の」is not possible)

2.
for 「思う」
○「感じる」　△「考える」

---

natural

> この文の中で　あなたが　おかしいと　思うところは？
>   あなたが　この文の中で　おかしいと　思うところは？

not in dayly use

> この文章について、あなたがおかしいと思うところを挙げなさい (テストでの設問)

acceptable

> あなたが　この文で　おかしいと　思うところは？

not acceptable

> あなたが この文の おかしいと 思うところは？ (この文「の」is not possible)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I'll give my answer.

Natural/unnatural aside, the OP is asking specifically about the structure of the sentence

> あなたがこの文のおかしいと思うところは？

It is true that this structure is a bit unusual and not so straight forward for a English speaker, but here's how to break it down:

> [あなたが][[この文のおかしい]と思う][ところ]は？

この文のおかしいと思う is what we'd call a relative clause in English that modifies ところ, and means

> [1この文]の[2おかしい]と[3思う][4ところ] 
> [4places] that [3(you) think] [1this article] is [2strange]

Why の? Well, that's because in ancient Japanese, の and が were interchangeable. Look up のーが conversion. That practice is still around today, but its use is restricted to subordinate clauses only.

For example: `海の見える街 = 海が見える街` but `見て！海が見える ≠ 見て！海の見える`. In fact, the latter is just plain wrong in Modern Japanese. So

> この文**の**おかしいと思うところ = この文**が**おかしいと思うところ

So to your question:

1. Yes grammatically I find no problem with `僕は君の好きなのは…`, but virtually no one speaks like this.　It’s grammatical but not idiomatic.
2. As I said, のーが conversion applies in most, if not all, relative clauses so `海の見える街`　`雰囲気の悪いところ` and `お金のない人` are all examples.